# Bootstrap cell expand when hovered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overlay, overlap

I have a simple bootstrap 3*2 grid and I would like the cell to expand and take all space in the grid when hovered.

Here is the code snippet of the initial position :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   4
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   5
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   6
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Examples :
I would like the column 2 to expand  only to the left, right and down. And fill the grid space
Or the column 1 to expand only to the right and down. And fill the grid space

Here are visual descriptions of the animation:
[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmaJd.png)
[Final state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6hEZ.png)

Comment: can you provide a code snippet, please?

Comment: I think you need to use the css properties of animate and. transform to achieve that.

Comment: Updated my post ! Sorry for the poor detailed question:(

Comment: I was  able to make this work, but by using absolute positioning only on the cell content. If you try to expand the parent column it breaks the Bootstrap grid and becomes a mess. Yet, what would be the use case? It seemed like something that would annoy users and that wouldn't work on a mobile. Anyway, I think you are more likely to get help with this if you first try to solve the problem yourself. Share your html and code even if not working.